# Burninate the [worst-case] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, burninate-request

[worst-case](/questions/tagged/worst-case) has 34 questions with it and no tag wiki.  Many of the questions appear to be very close to not constructive/too localized i.e *what's the best case/worst-case for this?*

Unless my lack of experience in the [complexity](/questions/tagged/complexity) (which many of these are also tagged with) is showing, this seems like a candidate to be burninated. Can we burninate this tag?

<sup>*what's the worst-**case** that could happen?*</sup>

Comment: 34 questions? Just remove it yourself and it'll disappear in a day

Comment: Correct,  but someone could create it again.  Do we really need this tag?

Comment: Someone could recreate it if it was burninated by a moderator too...

Comment: @animuson I guess my question also is, if this is a valid tag?  I don't see the use for it that I why I am asking.

Comment: Granted I'm relatively new to SO, but I feel that burninating is unnecessary in this case. The tag is used monthly, and someone could easily write a tag wiki for it. I would do it were it not for my low rep. Furthermore, just because some of the questions are close to not constructive/too localized does not mean _all_ are. IMO tags should be judged by their best case usage scenario, not the worst where users ask near not constructive/too localized questions (pun partially intended).