# Migrate or flag questions on MSE with stackoverflow tag?

Tags: discussion, flags, migration, off-topic

In the MSE review queue, there are a few close flags for "*question pertains only to a specific site*", most seem to be questions specific to MSO tagged with [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow).
They all seem to be before the split.

**1)**
Should we be closing these due to "*question pertains only to a specific site*", or should (someone) migrate them over to MSO?
If the latter, should we be flagging them for CM attention?
(Or would I likely get an unpleasant visit from a CM wielding a rusty-nailed baseball bat?)

**2)**
Would it be logical to migrate all questions on MSE tagged [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) over to MSO?

While that could move *legit MSE questions* which are just incorrectly tagged [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) (and other potential reasons), I mention it as someone with more knowledge of tags (etc) and access to data/databases etc could perhaps do some queries and see quickly if that is the case - based on what other tags the question has.

e.g. - If a question on MSE only has [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) *and/or* [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) *and/or* [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) (etc), could it be logically migrated?

---

### Example

[Burninate the [worst-case] tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182202/burninate-the-worst-case-tag)

It is perfectly logical closing that Q due to "is specific to another site", however only due to the MSO/MSE split, as the question was posted before it.
Wouldn't it be better for future reference (etc) if it was migrated to MSO - rather than the split *causing* questions to suddenly be off-topic?

Surely any site changes should also clean such things up (I'm not demanding, I'm sure you're all busy etc ;) ).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215677/when-mse-splits-from-mso-what-content-will-be-quickly-migrated-back-to-mso

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll answer your second question first: **it makes no sense to mass-migrate everything in [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow)**. Some of them are [not at all SO-specific](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user) and are heavily-referenced by other discussions here - feel free to re-tag these as you come across them. Others are just noise, and moving them around helps no one.

To your first question... Some of them should be closed. Most of them don't need to be moved though. Some of them should be deleted. The rest are fine where they sit.

Please don't close questions just because they happen to have been written in the context of Stack Overflow. If they are truly *only relevant to SO and no other site*, then fine, close. But if you're not sure, go find something else to do.

Flag questions for migration only if they're directly relevant to Stack Overflow *today* - and not relevant to any other site. In particular, be quick to flag questions that are being referenced frequently on MSO... And be very reluctant to flag questions that are heavily referenced here on MSE.

Above all, **do not flag things en masse based on simple keyword matches** - if a crapload of flags appear and we get the notion that you're just flagging based on the tag and haven't put any real thought into it, we'll decline them as a group without even looking at them.

#### How to evaluate a question

Tag-based discussions (retag-requst, burninate-request, etc.) make pretty good examples: they're *usually* SO-specific, and *occasionally* worth migrating. Here are the criteria I use for these:

- Does the problem described in the question still exist (is the tag still around, and still causing issues)?
- Is the question focused and clear (some folks like to throw up "burn them all!" discussions with a bunch of tangentially-related tags - those suck, delete them don't migrate them)?
- Is there any useful research or discussion present in the question or answers (did someone put some work into arguing why the tag is harmful / useful)?
- Are you personally going to make an effort to move the discussion forward once it is migrated (if you don't have any interest in the topic, leave it for someone else)?

If the answer to **all** of those is "yes", then flag it for migration. If the answer to **all** of them is "no", flag it for deletion. Otherwise, just leave it be.

In the case of the example you cite, there's absolutely no reason to migrate that - the issue is long-ago resolved, and there's nothing particularly valuable in the discussion there worth preserving. It could be deleted or just ignored.

Comment: hey, mass closes of these questions, [however bad](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254395/839601 "'For the most part, it's a gigantic waste of time and effort...'"), are probably my only chance to get Reviewer badge in MSE CV queue before bounties drop my rep under 3K :)

Comment: Perhaps I'm in the minority given your 6 upvotes, but you seem to have skipped my question & ideas. I didn't suggest we "flag things en masse based on simple keyword matches", I suggested someone with DB access could perhaps *investigate*. Users are *right now* flagging to *close* questions which are only off-topic due to the split. I asked if perhaps those questions would be better migrated to MSO where they would be on-topic, instead of being closed. You suggest we flag, or poke a CM, but then say not to do it "en masse". So, should we only try to fix a few off-topic questions?

Comment: "*Most don't need to be moved. Some deleted. rest fine where they sit*" Granted, but how do users identify those scenarios? In reality, they should all be cleaned up en masse, but not by flags, votes, or bothering CM - hence my entire question here, really.

Comment: See edits, @James.

Comment: Is nice that someone already said this, I have been editing and voting to reopen several questions where the only thing wrong was that they said "Stack( )+Overflow" somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. My example question is not ideal for all arguments, as it's burninate and status-completed it wont be duped on MSO or need to be searched for (the tag is gone). However, for other similar  questions (not burninate) migration would stop potential dupes on MSO, and provide info in the right place. Otherwise just closing questions on MSE which are MSO specific surely opens up potential for dupes between MSO/MSE? And users on MSO would need to search MSE for MSO answers. Seems messy to me, hence my idea to move them over.

Comment: Again, unless there is extensive, productive discussion there's little value in migrating these to avoid duplicates @James - if anyone actually cares, asking them again will restart the discussion and perhaps this time produce results; if no one cares, then they're just cruft.

Comment: I still think migration would be cleaner, but my opinion is on face value whereas, with absolute sincerity, you know better than I about what's likely pointless/useful etc in terms of *work required vs results gained* in these things. I'll just vote to close as "pertains to specific site" (where appropriate) on the ones frequenting the MSE queue ATM - as someone seems to be doing a spring clean of them all.