# Acting on some highly-upvoted badge requests

Tags: discussion, badges, meta, badge-request

The [badge-request] tag here has some [highly upvoted proposals with no clear status](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bbadge-request%5d%20-%5bstatus*%5d%20is%3aanswer%20).

Some of them should perhaps be "closed" as [status-declined] or similar, so that the actual badge proposals enjoying some consensus can stand out.

Comment: +1 not sure why this is being downvoted - it's not saying they must all be implemented yesterday, it's just saying that it'd be nice to see their status (which are being implemented, which are declined, etc).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133080/when-will-a-feature-request-be-marked-as-either-status-completed-or-status-decli and  more

Comment: Nemo, you're right now proposing some edits here which add the [stackoverflow] tag to questions. Please don't do that - questions about Stack Overflow should be asked on Meta Stack Overflow, they're here because of the [Meta Split](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014). Adding tags to them does not add any value.

Comment: @Glorfindel I know of the Meta split, that's why I'm adding the tag. Is there another tag for questions that should not be here?

Comment: In theory, they should be flagged for closure (*off-topic* -> *pertains only to a specific site*). In practice, this is only done for new questions - questions which are four years old are usually left alone.

Comment: @Glorfindel was there a discussion on this practice? I'd like to be able to filter SO-specific questions in my searches, the tag is very useful for me.

Comment: All *valuable* content here, specific to Stack Overflow, has already been migrated to Meta Stack Overflow. I suppose that if you do find a valuable question which isn't, you can use a custom flag for migration.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242810/295232) is some context provided by an SE employee.